# Using Javascript modules in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, module, webkit

I have a simple multi-module javasSript app and I want to use this JavaScript code in iOS App , but it seems that WKWebView doesn't recognize 'import' keyword 
is [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) code is supporting ECMAScript6 or there is another solutions

this code not run in WKWebView

```
import {sum} for "./Calculator"

function printResult(){
 console.log(sum(2,4)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKWebView or JavaScriptCore not support ES6 and you have to convert it to ES5 using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or http://browserify.org/

Comment: Is this still up to date? Do you have a source for that info, or was it according to tests?